# How to add decimals to dropdown lists from a cell range in Google Sheets

Tags: validation, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, calculated-columns

I have created a cost calculator on Google Sheets with data validation to display the values in columns Cost 1, Cost 2, Cost 3, etc. The only issue is, that when I click in the cell to display the dropdown list, it does 2 things:

- Doesn't display the currency symbol, in this case, the dollar
  sign.
- If a value is 20.00, 30.00 etc it just shows it as 20 or
  30. If the value is 20.50, it displays 20.5. If the value is 20.99 it shows it as 20.99.

How can I:

1. Display the currency symbol in the dropdown list
2. Display the exact value eg. 20.00 not 20 / 30.50 not 30.5

(1) is not essential, but (2) is preferred.

It's worth mentioning that when an option is selected from the dropdown list, both A and B is displayed in the cell, this is about what's displayed in the dropdown.

Thank you.

| Cost 1 | Cost 2 | Cost 3 | Selected Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $20.00 | $35.50 | $50 | $20.00 |

[dropdown screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9VTt.png)

[data validation screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3HII.png)

Comment: For the cell as desired. After selecting value from drop down list it will show desired format in cell. Drop down list shows actual values not formats.

Answer (score 0):

format your range F6:H6 as Text. this way you can add $ symbol and decimals and if your dropdown is used in further calculation you can regex-out the symbol and convert it back into value